# ASP NET Core (.NET 5) Identity system - Simple Login as a Temporary Workaround

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, identity

Is there anything you can setup with the help of startup class and maybe a cshtml file to provide a simple way for developer(s) to log in and log out as the same user to get a web development project moving again... while another proper (yet buggy) system is being developed by another team?

There are 4 developers completely stuck on a project because of the inability to just login to the site while this other system is setup. All the features they need to work on are related to being authenticated and that custom experience. Thoughts? Workarounds? Hacks we can use to get moving again? I have been away from .NET for about 4 years after about 14 in the trenches. And the security stuff was never my area of expertise. Especially now with Core.

Comment: Why can't they create accounts and log in?

Comment: Let's describe more clear about your need.

Comment: It seems that you want to add the login function to the existing project, right? you could check the [Identity document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio), then use [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to genreate the related page (login, register, etc)

Comment: Noah, has something to do with getting Identity Server 4 working in Containerized Environment on AWS. It intermittingly fails. This is going on two weeks.